# Using multiple predicates at different levels in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml file:

```xml
<foo class="class1">
 <bar class="title">
  <span> HELLO WORLD </span>
 </bar>
 <bar class="desc">
   <span> I don't want this text </span>
 </bar>
</foo>
```

I want to isolate `HELLO WORLD` using the `class` attributes.

An example of what I have tried (but is not correct) is:
`//*[@class="class1"]/[@class="title"]`

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an asterisk and a span:

```
//*[@class="class1"]/*[@class="title"]/span
```

But this would probably suffice:

```
//*[@class="title"]/span
```

Comment: I need the first one because my real xml file has a lot of repeats... all that for an asterisk, thanks so much!